# ggplot with posterior distribution plotted over geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian

I'd like to recreate this plot from this blog post on [Posterior predicted distribution for linear regression in JAGS](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2015/10/posterior-predicted-distribution-for.html)) using ggplot?

[image]

Knowing all the extras available for ggplot, what methods are there to go about this?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for when you say "better"? What are the feature that are important/missing? Your plot already looks different from the example. It would probably be better to remove your "answer" from the question and post that part as an answer below. Then people can vote on it or provide an alternative solution.

Comment: @MrFlick by "better" I mean this is the first time I've had a ggplot question where I couldn't find the solution already on SO :) . I'm assuming that someone already has done this and am looking for what they might have done. I appreciate your thought and will move my solution to answer if no alternatives posted soonish

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare-bones example of what I've come up with using `density` to add a `geom_path`.

```
library(ggplot2)
#mydat <- read.csv("HtWt30.csv")

mydat <- structure(list(male = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                        height = c(64, 62.3, 67.9, 64.2, 64.8, 57.5, 
                                   65.6, 70.2, 63.9, 71.1, 66.5, 68.1, 62.9, 75.1, 64.6, 69.2, 68.1, 
                                   72.6, 63.2, 64.1, 64.1, 71.5, 76, 69.7, 73.3, 61.7, 66.4, 65.7, 
                                   68.3, 66.9), 
                        weight = c(136.4, 215.1, 173.6, 117.3, 123.3, 96.5, 
                                   178.3, 191.1, 158, 193.9, 127.1, 147.9, 119, 204.4, 143.4, 124.4, 
                                   140.9, 164.7, 139.8, 110.2, 134.1, 193.6, 180, 155, 188.2, 187.4, 
                                   139.2, 147.9, 178.6, 111.1)), 
                   .Names = c("male", "height", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))


# smooth plot
g_smooth <- ggplot(mydat, aes(x = height, y = weight)) + geom_smooth()

# fake posterior at a height = 60
p60 <- data.frame(x = 60, y = rnorm(1000, mean = 145, sd = 10))
# density kernel 
d60 <- density(p60$y)
# calculate scaling factor so that density covers 1/20 of full x range
density_scaling <- ((max(mydat$height) - min(mydat$height)) / 20) / max(d60$y)
# convert to points
d60points <- data.frame(y = d60$x, x = 60 + d60$y * density_scaling)
# add path to plot
g_smooth <- g_smooth + geom_path(data = d60points, aes(x = x, y = y))

# fake posterior at a height = 70
p70 <-  data.frame(x = 60, y = rnorm(1000, mean = 165, sd = 10))
# density kernel 
d70 <- density(p70$y)
# calculate scaling factor so that density covers 1/20 of full x range
density_scaling <- ((max(mydat$height) - min(mydat$height)) / 20) / max(d70$y)
# convert to points
d70points <- data.frame(y = d70$x, x = 70 + d70$y * density_scaling)
# add path to plot
g_smooth <- g_smooth + geom_path(data = d70points, aes(x = x, y = y))

g_smooth
```

[image]